# Writing a specific SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a database which saves data from a survey where one person can take survey one or two times, and not more than that. I have a column `DATE` through which I want to get all peoples first survey(not second one).

For example, the person with EMAIL `shane@gmail.com` has given survey on `DATE` 29th and 30th of December. Same way person with EMAIL `mike@gmail.com` has given survey on `DATE` 1st nov and 28th dec.

I want to get both persons first survey records. Thank you

Comment: What database are you using? What do you have so far?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempt at a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Might be good to give the schema of the tables.

Comment: try http://sqlfiddle.com/ for schema and table structure. will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Without the schema it's difficult to guess at what you need.  But if it's as simple as a table with email and survey dates it could be something like this:

```
select email, survey_date
from myTable
group by email
order by survey_date asc
```

Comment: If it's grouped by email, won't it just return a single record per unique email address?

Comment: when using `group by` on a column, you need to provide aggregate functions (*like `MIN` / `MAX`*) for the rest of the columns you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross the table with itself

```
select * from table t1 join table t2
on t1.email = t2.email 
and t1.surveydate < t2.surveydate
```

PS: you can optimize the query with a clause "WITH", if your database engine supports it. This query will work correctly as long as there only 2 records for each email as you have exposed